# Running ScalaTest suites (not tests) in parallel in sbt?

Tags: sbt, scalatest

I use SBT **0.13.1** and want to run [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) test suites in parallel (not tests within each suite).

I do *not* have `parallelExecution in Test := false` set, but it looks like test suites are run in serial order.

The experiment I did was:

```
class BlahSuite extends FunSuite {
  test("run 1") {
    println("running one")
    Console.err.flush()
    Console.out.flush()
    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }
}

class Blah2Suite extends FunSuite{
  test("run 2") {
    println("running two")
    Console.err.flush()
    Console.out.flush()
    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }
}
```

And I see `running two` printed 10 seconds after `running one`, which leads me to believe that `run 2` was not started until `run 1` finished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing differently, i have copied your code inside an empty SBT project (0.13.1) using Scala 2.10.3 and it runs in parallel by default, see my output:

```
running one
running two
[info] Blah2Suite:
[info] - run 2
[info] BlahSuite:
[info] - run 1
[info] Run completed in 10 seconds, 278 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 11 s, completed Mar 21, 2014 11:58:24 AM
```

Tried it with ScalaTest version 2.1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: This is correct. The default in sbt is parallel execution, and the default way to do parallel execution in ScalaTest is running Suites in parallel. The only thing that comes to mind is if you are doing this via Play, Play turns off parallel execution. You may wish to try adding an explicit parallelExecution in Test := true to your build.